# Filter mulitple Search Console queries with Data Studio

Tags: looker-studio

I want to show the average positions of some given queries from the Search Console.
I set:
Dimension = Query
Metric = Average Position

And than I add a filter for a query with "Equal to (=)" following by the query. That works well for just one query. It shows only that query in the table.

But when I add another query in the same filter with "OR" and than "Equal to (=)" a second query (see snippet), it doesn't work anymore: gives an error.

[image: snippet]

Any idea?

Comment: What's the error and does it do the same if you use Query IN ('compare energy','cheapest contract')?

Comment: The error is: Data Set Configuration Error
Data Studio cannot connect to your data set.

Failed to fetch data from the underlying data set

Error ID: 6799f876

Comment: when I do Query IN ('compare energy','cheapest contract') it says "no data"

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution with thanks to @Bobbylank:

Works with

> Query IN compare energy,cheapest contract

So without quotes and parentheses.